# Cannot embed image to dynamucally binded richtext item in Xpage

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I have a quiz form, which lets to create different psychological tests. Now it hardcoded to 50 questions. I need some questions to have embedded images, that's why I use RichText. When I bind it dynamically, with `value="#{document1[viewScope.FieldName]}"` it works fine with custom text formatting, but don't let me import an image into richtext. Binding with `value="${document1[viewScope.FieldName]}"` lets, but I can't dynamically change fields.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="test">

        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>

    <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (!viewScope.qNum || viewScope.qNum == 0) {
    viewScope.qNum = 1;
}
viewScope.qFNCount = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'Count';
viewScope.qFNCorrect = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'Correct';
viewScope.qFNTitle = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'Title';
viewScope.qFNA1 = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'A1';
viewScope.qFNA2 = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'A2';
viewScope.qFNA3 = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'A3';
viewScope.qFNA4 = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'A4';
viewScope.qFNA5 = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'A5';}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
    <xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:
viewScope.qFNCount = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'Count';
viewScope.qFNCorrect = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'Correct';
viewScope.qFNTitle = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'Title';
viewScope.qFNA1 = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'A1';
viewScope.qFNA2 = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'A2';
viewScope.qFNA3 = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'A3';
viewScope.qFNA4 = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'A4';
viewScope.qFNA5 = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'A5';}]]></xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
    <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock2">
    <xp:this.value>
        <![CDATA[
            CKEDITOR.config.removeButtons = 'TextColor,BGColor,Find,Font,Underline,Subscript,Superscript,Scayt,Anchor,Table,HorizontalRule,SpecialChar,Maximize,Strike,NumberedList,BulletedList,Indent,Outdent,Blockquote,Styles,Format,About';
        ]]>
    </xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>


    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/application.css"></xp:styleSheet>
        <xp:script src="/core.ssjs.jss" clientSide="false"></xp:script>
        <xp:script src="/client.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
        <xp:script src="/form.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
    </xp:this.resources>

    <xp:panel styleClass="container form-horizontal" id="container">

        <xe:djHorizontalSlider id="djHorizontalSlider1"
            value="#{viewScope.qNum}" clickSelect="true" maximum="50" minimum="1"
            pageIncrement="1" showButtons="true" required="true"
            style="overflow:hidden" readOnly="false" discreteValues="50"
            lang="ru" slideDuration="50">
            <xe:this.converter>
                <xp:convertNumber integerOnly="true"></xp:convertNumber>
            </xe:this.converter>
            <xe:djSliderRuleLabels
                style="height:14px;font-size:75%;color:gray" count="50"
                container="bottomDecoration" id="djSliderRuleLabels1" maximum="50"
                minimum="1" labels="#{javascript:rangeStr(1,51)}">

            </xe:djSliderRuleLabels>


            <xp:eventHandler event="onChange" submit="true"
                refreshMode="complete">
                <xe:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.qFNTitle = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'Title';
viewScope.qFNCount = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'Count';
viewScope.qFNCorrect = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'Correct';
viewScope.qFNA1 = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'A1';
viewScope.qFNA2 = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'A2';
viewScope.qFNA3 = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'A3';
viewScope.qFNA4 = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'A4';
viewScope.qFNA5 = 'Q'+viewScope.qNum + 'A5';}]]></xe:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xe:djHorizontalSlider>
        <xp:panel styleClass="panel panel-default" id="quests">
            <xp:panel styleClass="panel-body">
                <xc:ccSectionPanel panel_id="ccSection"
                    initClosed="false" panel_class="panel-default" footer="false"
                    disable_collapse="true"
                    titleBarText="#{javascript:'Вопрос номер ' + viewScope.qNum;}"
                    custom_title="true">
                    <xp:this.facets>
                        <xp:panel xp:key="customTitle">
                        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"
                            value="#{javascript:'Вопрос номер ' + viewScope.qNum;}"
                            styleClass="panel-title">
                        </xp:text>
                        <xp:button value="Редактировать" id="button2"
                            rendered="#{javascript:document1.isEditable()==@False()}"
                            styleClass="pull-right"
                            style="margin-top:-7px;margin-right:-12px;">

                            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
                                submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
                                <xp:this.action>

                                    <xp:actionGroup>
                                        <xp:changeDocumentMode
                                            mode="edit" var="document1">
                                        </xp:changeDocumentMode>
                                        <xp:executeScript>
                                            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.put("editmode", true)}]]></xp:this.script>
                                        </xp:executeScript>
                                    </xp:actionGroup>
                                </xp:this.action>
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                        </xp:button>
                        <xp:button value="Сохранить" id="button1"
                            rendered="#{javascript:document1.isEditable()}"
                            styleClass="pull-right"
                            style="margin-top:-7px;margin-right:-12px;">
                            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
                                submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
                                <xp:this.action>


                                    <xp:actionGroup>
                                        <xp:actionGroup>
                                            <xp:saveDocument
                                                var="document1">
                                            </xp:saveDocument>
                                            <xp:changeDocumentMode
                                                mode="readOnly" var="document1">
                                            </xp:changeDocumentMode>
                                        </xp:actionGroup>
                                        <xp:executeScript>
                                            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.put("editmode", false)}]]></xp:this.script>
                                        </xp:executeScript>
                                    </xp:actionGroup>
                                </xp:this.action>
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                        </xp:button>
                        </xp:panel>
                        <xp:panel xp:key="panelBody">
                            <xc:ссFormGroup fg_id="fgTitle"
                                editmode="true" label_target="inputRichTextTitle">
                                <xc:this.label_text><![CDATA[#{javascript:'Заголовок вопроса [' + viewScope.qFNTitle + ']'}]]></xc:this.label_text>
                                <xp:this.facets>
                                    <xp:inputRichText
                                        id="inputRichTextTitle" xp:key="fieldFacet"
                                        value="#{document1[viewScope.qFNTitle]}">
                                    </xp:inputRichText>
                                </xp:this.facets>
                            </xc:ссFormGroup>
                            <xc:ссFormGroup fg_id="fgCountAnswers"
                                editmode="true" label_target="radioGroup1">
                                <xc:this.label_text><![CDATA[#{javascript:'Количество вариантов ответа [' + viewScope.qFNCount + ']'}]]></xc:this.label_text>
                                <xp:this.facets>
                                    <xp:radioGroup id="radioGroup1"
                                        xp:key="fieldFacet" defaultValue="4"
                                        value="#{document1[viewScope.qFNCount]}">
                                        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="1"></xp:selectItem>
                                        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="2"></xp:selectItem>
                                        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="3"></xp:selectItem>
                                        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="4"></xp:selectItem>
                                        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="5"></xp:selectItem>
                                        <xp:eventHandler
                                            event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
                                            refreshId="container">
                                        </xp:eventHandler>
                                    </xp:radioGroup>
                                </xp:this.facets>
                            </xc:ссFormGroup>
                            <xc:ссFormGroup fg_id="fgA1" editmode="true"
                                label_target="inputRichTextA1">
                                <xc:this.label_text><![CDATA[#{javascript:'Ответ 1 [' + viewScope.qFNA1 + ']'}]]></xc:this.label_text>
                                <xp:this.facets>
                                    <xp:inputRichText
                                        id="inputRichTextA1" xp:key="fieldFacet"
                                        value="#{document1[viewScope.qFNA1]}">
                                    </xp:inputRichText>
                                </xp:this.facets>
                            </xc:ссFormGroup>


                            <xc:ссFormGroup fg_id="fgA2" editmode="true"
                                label_target="inputRichTextA2">
                                <xc:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:count = document1.getItemValueString(viewScope.qFNCount);
if (!count || count == '') {count = 4}
count > 1}]]></xc:this.rendered>
                                <xc:this.label_text><![CDATA[#{javascript:'Ответ 2 [' + viewScope.qFNA2 + ']'}]]></xc:this.label_text>
                                <xp:this.facets>
                                    <xp:inputRichText
                                        id="inputRichTextA2" xp:key="fieldFacet"
                                        value="#{document1[viewScope.qFNA2]}">
                                    </xp:inputRichText>
                                </xp:this.facets>
                            </xc:ссFormGroup>


                            <xc:ссFormGroup fg_id="fgA3" editmode="true"
                                label_target="inputRichTextA3">
                                <xc:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:count = document1.getItemValueString(viewScope.qFNCount);
if (!count || count == '') {count = 4}
count > 2}]]></xc:this.rendered>
                                <xc:this.label_text><![CDATA[#{javascript:'Ответ 3 [' + viewScope.qFNA3 + ']'}]]></xc:this.label_text>
                                <xp:this.facets>
                                    <xp:inputRichText
                                        id="inputRichTextA3" xp:key="fieldFacet"
                                        value="#{document1[viewScope.qFNA3]}">


                                    </xp:inputRichText>
                                </xp:this.facets>
                            </xc:ссFormGroup>


                            <xc:ссFormGroup fg_id="fgA4" editmode="true"
                                label_target="inputRichTextA4">
                                <xc:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:count = document1.getItemValueString(viewScope.qFNCount);
if (!count || count == '') {count = 4}
count > 3}]]></xc:this.rendered>
                                <xc:this.label_text><![CDATA[#{javascript:'Ответ 4 [' + viewScope.qFNA4 + ']'}]]></xc:this.label_text>
                                <xp:this.facets>
                                    <xp:inputRichText
                                        id="inputRichTextA4" xp:key="fieldFacet"
                                        value="#{document1[viewScope.qFNA4]}">
                                    </xp:inputRichText>
                                </xp:this.facets>
                            </xc:ссFormGroup>


                            <xc:ссFormGroup fg_id="fgA5" editmode="true"
                                label_target="inputRichTextA5">
                                <xc:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:count = document1.getItemValueString(viewScope.qFNCount);
if (!count || count == '') {count = 4}
count > 4}]]></xc:this.rendered>
                                <xc:this.label_text><![CDATA[#{javascript:'Ответ 5 [' + viewScope.qFNA5 + ']'}]]></xc:this.label_text>
                                <xp:this.facets>
                                    <xp:inputRichText
                                        id="inputRichTextA5" xp:key="fieldFacet"
                                        value="#{document1[viewScope.qFNA5]}">
                                    </xp:inputRichText>
                                </xp:this.facets>
                            </xc:ссFormGroup>



                            <xc:ссFormGroup fg_id="fg1" editmode="true"
                                label_target="radioGroupCorrect">
                                <xc:this.label_text><![CDATA[#{javascript:'Верный ответ [' + viewScope.qFNCorrect + ']'}]]></xc:this.label_text>
                                <xp:this.facets>
                                    <xp:radioGroup
                                        id="radioGroupCorrect" xp:key="fieldFacet"
                                        value="#{document1[viewScope.qFNCorrect]}">
                                        <xp:selectItems>
                                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var count = document1.getItemValueString(viewScope.qFNCount);
if (!count || count == '') {count = 4}
count++;
rangeStr(1,count)}]]></xp:this.value>
                                        </xp:selectItems>
                                    </xp:radioGroup>
                                </xp:this.facets>
                            </xc:ссFormGroup>
                        </xp:panel>
                    </xp:this.facets>

                </xc:ccSectionPanel>
            </xp:panel>
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:panel></xp:view>
```

The simplest and most brutal solution is to create 50*7 static fields with dynamic render state. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative and probably better approach then is to create questions in separate documents. Then you don't have to dynamically bind to a field. It's one I've used on at least two similar occasions.

The driver for using fields in one document is often habit. Traditional Domino web or Notes Client typically required everything to be in the same document. XPages doesn't. Break the habit and you remove the problem.

One change that will be required is to create and save the quiz before adding questions. There are a variety of reasons why this is actually a better approach, for a web app and a quiz with a number of questions.